# Ubuntu remote server control from other network

Tags: server, 14.10, vpn, remote-desktop, file-sharing

Hello everyone today i worked on an old laptop i had with ubuntu 14.10 on it. I can now remote acces it from my home wifi connection. But i was wondering what if i want to acces it from a train with Wi-Fi. So i googled but not allot of succes. All i know is that i need to setup a vpn but how do i set up a vpn for accesing it remotely. Could anyone please help me in the right direction. I don't need a total answer but you can just push me in the right direction. Because i like to find stuff out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same thing with a debian, using ssh.

First of all, you should be sure that your IP is not dynamic (otherwise, look at a service like no-ip). After that, you have to open your ssh port (default, 22 - but I suggest to change it) in your router and you're free to access your ubuntu using ssh

For a grafic interface, I usually run a tightvncserver from ssh and then I connect to it with any vnc client

Answer (score 0):

What exact kind of access are you looking to get?  Just ftp access to files, or use your computer as if you were there?

If the former, then SSH would be your best bet.  Have your modem/router forward the SSH request ports to your computer, and just use sftp user@global.ip.address.here, to get in.

If the latter, there are a few different ways to set up a VPN, depending on your network hardware/setup.  First, if you just have a simple modem/router, you'll probably have to set up a server/service for the connection, and have your modem/router forward the ports to that server.  If you have a more intelligent modem/router, then you could configure VPN directly on that device.

Note that with VPN, you will have to generate keys and certificates to create this link.